# NestJs: Imported service can not be found when running custom commands from Nest Commander

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a module called `WebscraperModule` with a service called `WebscaperService`. Within the `WebscraperService` I am importing another service `GeoCodingService` from another module `GeoCodingModule`.
From the `GeoCodingModule` I am exporting the `GeoCodingService` and importing it into the `WebscraperModule`. I believe I have imported everything correctly and the import paths when clicked all take to the correct Modules/Services. However, when I call the  `WebscaperService` with my custom commands created using the Nest Commander package I get the error `Error: Cannot find module 'src/@geoCoding/services/geoCoding.service'`. When running
`npm run start:dev` I get no errors, so I'm thinking I've not set up the Commander package properly. How can I can fix this?

Command module

```
@Module({
    providers: [ WebscraperCommand ],
    imports:   [ WebscraperModule ],
    exports:   [ WebscraperCommand ]
})
export class CommandsModule {}
```

Webscraper.command.ts

```
import { WebscraperService } from 'src/@webScraper/services/webscraper.service';

  @Command({ name: 'basic', description: 'A parameter parse' })
  export class WebscraperCommand extends CommandRunner {

    constructor(private readonly webscraperService: WebscraperService) {
        super();
    };
      
    async run() : Promise<void> {
      console.log("run")
        this.callMainScrapper();
    };

    @Option({
      flags: '-msc',
      description: 'Call the main scraper',
    })

    callMainScrapper(){     
     console.log("run");
     this.webscraperService.mainScraper();
    };

  };
```

GeoCoding Module

```
@Global()
  @Module({
    imports: [ HttpModule, ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }) ],
    providers: [ GeoCodingService ],
    exports: [ GeoCodingService ]
    })

export class GeoCodingModule {}
```

GeoCoding Service

```
@Injectable()
export class GeoCodingService {

    constructor( 
      private readonly _httpService: HttpService, 
      private readonly _configService: ConfigService 
      ) {};

    public coordinates : object = {};
    
    private _logger = new Logger('GeoCodingService');             
    private _apiKey : string = this._configService.get('API_KEY');

    public async getGeoCoding(address: string): Promise<void> {

        const result : unknown = address.match(/^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}$/i);

        const url : string = `https://api.tomtom.com/search/2/geocode/${result[0].toUpperCase()}&limit=1.json?key=${this._apiKey}`;

        let res : object = {};

        try {

          this._httpService.get(url).then(response => {

            if (response.data.results[0].position === undefined) {
  
              res = {};
  
            } else {
  
              res = response.data.results[0].position;

            };
  
            this.coordinates = res;
  
          });

        } catch (error: any) {

          this._logger.error(error.message, error.stack);

        };
    };
};
```

Webscraper module

```
  @Global()
  @Module({
    imports: [ GeoCodingModule, HttpModule, ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true
    }), ],
    exports: [ WebscraperService],
    providers: [WebscraperService, WebscraperCommand],
    })

export class WebscraperModule {};
```

Webscraper service

```
import { GeoCodingService } from 'src/@geoCoding/services/geoCoding.service';
//This is the line in question

export class WebscraperService {

  constructor( 
    private _geoCodingService: GeoCodingService,
    private readonly _httpService: HttpService, 
    private readonly _configService: ConfigService
    ) {};


 private async _getDataFromPage() : Promise<void> {

      for (const anchorLink of this._anchors) {
    
        const response : any = await fetch(anchorLink);
    
        const body : any = await response.text();

        this._setPropertyType(anchorLink);
    
        this._setProps(body);

        const slice: Array<string> = this._addressData.slice(0, -2);

        const addressToString = slice.toString()


        //getGeoCoding is called here
        this._geoCodingService.getGeoCoding(addressToString)


        
        const property : PropertyInterface = {
          address: addressToString,
          telephone: this._telephoneNumber,
          website: this._websiteLink,
          canLeaveDogsUnattended: this._dogsUnattended,
          maxDogs: this._numberOfDogs,
          extraCharge: this._charge,
          coordinates: this._coordinates,
          type: this._type
        };
  
      properties.push(property); 

      console.log(property, "property")

      await this._sleep(1000);
      
      };
    
    };


}
```

Comment: your `CommandsModule` needs to import your `GeoCodingModule`

Comment: Hello Liam, I've tried this but no luck I'm afraid. Thanks though.